# How to mock minio upload/download using pytest

Tags: pytest, minio

https://docs.min.io/docs/python-client-api-reference.html

I have some implementation like below

```
class Minio:
    def initialize(self):
        # Create client with access key and secret key with specific region.
        self.client = Minio(
            "play.minio.io:9000",
            access_key="access-key",
            secret_key="secret-key",
            region="my-region",
        )

    def upload_to_minio(self):
        ## code to upload file into minio
        result = self.client.fput_object(
            "my-bucket", "my-object", "my-filename",
        )
        print(
            "created {0} object; etag: {1}, version-id: {2}".format(
                result.object_name, result.etag, result.version_id,
            ),
        )

    def download_from_minio(self):
        ## code to download file from minio
        self.client.fget_object(
            "my-bucket", "my-object", "my-filename",
            version_id="dfbd25b3-abec-4184-a4e8-5a35a5c1174d",
        )
```

I want to write unit test using pytest for the above class.

Is there any package available to mock minio buckets and behaviours?

Or should we write a class for mock connection and validate the upload and download.

Can someone help on this ?

Comment: create your own mock objects to mock `Minio`?

Comment: Any link you can point to .. i am new to pytest

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/pytest-mock/ https://realpython.com/python-mock-library/

Comment: Have you considered using "boto3"? if you could switch to using "boto3" then you could use "moto" for mocking. Otherwise if you found a way to mock "minio" for pytest I would also be interested.

Comment: I ended up writing a plugin for pytest that mocks minio, I called it python-minio-mock.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and eventually I had to create a fixture that mocks minio.Minio(). I used the following solution:

in the conftest I define a fixture called `minio_mock`:

```
@pytest.fixture
def minio_mock(mocker):
    def minio_mock_init(
        cls,
        *args,
        **kwargs,
    ):
        return MockMinioClient(*args, **kwargs)

    patched = mocker.patch.object(Minio, "__new__", new=minio_mock_init)
    yield patched
```

By patching the `__new__` function of the class `Minio`, the `minio_mock` fixture yields a `MockMinioClient` objects whenever a `Minio` object is created.

The class `MockMinioClient` is defined as follows:

class MockMinioClient:
buckets = {}

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # dealing with initialzing the object...

def list_buckets(self):
    try:
        return self.buckets
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
```

Eventually I wrote a plugin for pytest and I just published the version 0.1.2 of the plugin.

You can find the source code here https://github.com/oussjarrousse/pytest-minio-mock

you can download it with pip as in:

`pip3 install pytest-minio-mock` this will provide the fixture minio_mock that patches Minio() and replaces it with MockMinioClient.

Also you can read about it here:
https://blog.jarrousse.org/2024/01/03/introducing-pytest-minio-mock